# Unable to Debug Web Application with LocalHost

Tags: .net, iis, localhost

I have a web application that was originally built in VS 2008. Over the years it has been migrated thru VS 2010 to VS 2015. It runs just fine and has gone thru numerous code changes and debugging. Recently we moved the code to a new server and now I can't debug it. When it tries to connect to localhost I get the following error: This page cannot be displayed. Make sure the web address http://localhost:1605/Default.aspx is correct.

I can telnet into the port, so I know it is opening. I have created a NEW .net web app and localhost works correctly and the page opens. I don't know what I need to do to get the code to open in localhost so I can test new code changes.

If I've interpreted the request from Jalpa correctly, here is a pic of the Site solution. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the hosting environnement ? Full IIS ? IIS express ?

Comment: if you are working in visual studio please check did you start the IIS Express? You can do it by selecting Debug - Start debugging F5. check your site configuration detail that the url is correct or not.

Comment: Hosting environment - I'm guessing it is IIS Express. While I have IIS on the server, the properties refer to "default web server". As for whether it is starting, I would have to say yes. One thing I noticed is that the "app" was written as Web Site and Not a Web App (it doesn't have a .csproj or .vbproj file. Not sure how I was able to debug it in VS 2015 on another server.

Comment: check your web.config file <compilation debug="true"> is set or not. try to delete the content from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`. if possible share your visual studio site screenshot.

Comment: This is what is in the webconfig: <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>. Posted pic of site above.